# Html horizontal navigation menus

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am using a Html navigation menu on a website using the standard UL LI approach. But the problem is that when I resize the browser window the menu is resized and menu items outside the viewable area are shifted downwards. Has any on faced a similar problem? 
Html

```
<div style="margin-top: 11px; display: block;" class="menubar">
<ul class="tabs">
            <li ><a  href="#">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Menu4</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Menu5</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Menu6</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .menubar {
background: url("images/bg.png") repeat scroll left top #222222;
border-bottom: 1px solid #B2D7FC;
border-top: 1px solid #B2D7FC;
color: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
height: 35px;
margin: 10px 0 0;
padding: 0 2%;
width: 96%;
}
ul.tabs {
display: block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 5px 0 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul.tabs li {
background: url("images/tab_right.png") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
float: left;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Code, please. How can we possibly fix a code related problem when all we see is words?

Comment: Without any code I assume the problem you are having is that the container of the menu doesn't have a min-width specified, therefor they move below each other when the container becomes smaller then combined width of the menu.

Comment: Try to give fixed Height and width to your div. or try with min-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please define its `width` if you are not given like

```
div
 { width:size %/px/em;
   min-width:%/px/em;
   position:absolute;
  }
```

Comment: Min-Width was the problem and setting it solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set a `min-width` on your container, or the `<ul>`.

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    min-width:720px;
}
```

Change the `720px` to however large you want the menu to be. That way, it will resize until it hits that limit.